# Converting Integers to Characters in Common Lisp

Tags: type-conversion, common-lisp

Is there a way to parse integers to their char equivalents in Common Lisp?

I've been looking all morning, only finding `char-int`...

```
* (char-int #\A)

65
```

Some other sources also claim the existance of `int-char`

```
* (int-char 65)
; in: INT-CHAR 65
;     (INT-CHAR 65)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: INT-CHAR
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     INT-CHAR
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition

debugger invoked on a UNDEFINED-FUNCTION:
  The function COMMON-LISP-USER::INT-CHAR is undefined.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

("undefined function")
```

What I'm really looking for, however, is a way of converting `1` to `#\1`

How exactly would I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To convert between characters and their numeric encodings, there are `char-code` and `code-char`:

```
* (char-code #\A)
65
* (code-char 65)
#\A
```

However, to convert a digit to the corresponding character, there is `digit-char`:

```
* (digit-char 1)
#\1
* (digit-char 13 16) ; radix 16
#\D
```

Answer (score 7):

There's already an accepted answer, but it can be just as helpful to learn *how* to find the answer as getting the specific answer.  One way of finding the function you needed would have been to do an **apropos** search for "CHAR".  E.g., in CLISP, you'd get:

```
> (apropos "CHAR" "CL")
...
CHAR-CODE                                  function
...
CODE-CHAR                                  function
...
```

Another useful resource is the HyperSpec.  There's [permuted index](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/X_Perm_C.htm), and searching for "char" in the "C" page will be useful.  Alternatively, in the HyperSpec, the chapter [13. Characters](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/13_.htm) is relevant, and [13.2 The Characters Dictionary](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_charac.htm) would be useful.

Both of these approaches would also find the **digit-char** function mentioned in the other answer, too.